# Crop image inside scrollView at a specific area

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

### Issue

I am trying to crop an image inside `UIScrollView` at a specific area where the zoom scale of the `UIScrollView` when the image is `.AspectFit` on the crop frame is 1.

**The target size should be 800x800 px, .AspectFit on the crop frame, and the side spaces should be white.**

- `UIScrollView` (Green)
- Crop Frame is always 200x200 pt and on the center of `UIScrollView` (Red)
- `UIImageView` (Blue)

[image: ScrollView + ImageView + Crop Frame]

### My Approach

Based on the Apple Docs I can achieve this by finding the frame in unit coordinates of the original image, which I have achieved as below:

```
let offsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let normalizedX = (cropView.frame.origin.x + offsetX) / imageViewFrame.size.width
let normalizedY = (cropView.frame.origin.y + offsetY) / imageViewFrame.size.height
let normalizedWidth = 200.0 / imageViewFrame.size.width
let normalizedHeight = 200.0 / imageViewFrame.size.height

let cropRect = CGRect(x: normalizedX, y: normalizedY, width: normalizedWidth, height: normalizedHeight)
```

Then I based on this unit crop frame, I request the image from the assets with a specific target size (800x800 px).

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
options.networkAccessAllowed = true
options.normalizedCropRect = cropRect
options.resizeMode = .Exact

let targetSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 800)

PHImageManager
    .defaultManager()
    .requestImageForAsset(self.albumView.phAsset,
                          targetSize: targetSize,
                          contentMode: .AspectFit,
                          options: options) {
                            result, info in

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                completion(image: result)

                            })
}
```

### Problem

This approach seems to work really nice when the `contentSize` (either `width` or `height`) of the `UIScrollView` is bigger (or equal) to the `UIScrollView`'s `frame`. Otherwise it will the code above returns me the original image, which can be due to the fact that the unit frame goes out of [0, 1] segment.

And logically to achieve what I am expecting without going out of bounds, doesn't make sense, as the limiting factor will be increased.

Is there another way to actually crop an image inside that crop frame, and the result image would be an image **AspectFitted** to the cropFrame where the empty spaces would be white?

If anyone has any thought or opinion about this problem, you're welcome to answer it :)